# How to delete a column named grave accent in MySQL

Tags: mysql, alter-table

As title.

Every time when I try to execute the query:

````
ALTER TABLE tablename DROP COLUMN ```
````

I got syntax error, which is understandable.

So, what should I do to delete this column whose name is the symbol of grave accent?

Comment: How did you create it? (And why?) The same syntax you used then should work now.

Comment: after i executed an excel macro, the column is added. i don't really know the exact reason. sry abt that

Answer (score 2):

OK, I found out the answer.

The correct query should be

`````
alter table tablename drop column ````
`````

Answer (score -1):

```
alter table `tablename` Drop column `accent`
```

This will work you need to wrap with ``.
What is the error you are getting, what is your table name?

Comment: the thing is, the column name is the symbol of grave accent `, and when i execute [alter table tablename drop column ```] got error 1064

Comment: The table name appears in the question, and it is not 'accent'. -1